# Can you use Google Suite as an alternative to Zentyal?

Tags: networking, server, zentyal

My school has Google Suite but not Windows Domain Network because of GDPR and other legal considerations.(the school needs to make some sort of agreement and then we need a lawyer and we can't afford that)

Can you use G Suite as an alternative to Zentyal for Ubuntu, so that when you start the computer you put in your username and password and all your files, preferences, etc. load up, and when you log out it copies all files to Google Drive and the computer deletes all the files?

Can you get that function for Ubuntu with Google Suite?

If not, can you use Ubuntu Server in the same way as Windows Server?

Answer (score 0):

> Can you get that function for Ubuntu with Google Suite?

JumpCloud is a third-party cross-platform solution that adds to G Suite the capability to serve as a domain controller and enables admins to use their existing G Suite credentials for user access to all of their resources. Maybe JumpCloud is too expensive to use in a non-enterprise scenario.

> If not, can you use Ubuntu Server in the same way as Windows Server?

[Zenthyal](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/zentyal.html) is a Linux-based replacement for Microsoft Small Business Server and Microsoft Exchange Server based on Ubuntu. Zentyal can also be installed as a "package set" to an already installed version of Ubuntu Server.

*As [Zentyal](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fCOVHg5wP-s) comes with a native implementation of the Microsoft Active Directory protocols. It makes it easy to manage the domain and directory services typical to those of a Windows domain.* <sup>[Source](https://web.archive.org/web/20190421095728/https://zentyal.com/news/how-to-zentyal-as-a-stand-alone-domain-controller-video-tutorial/)</sup>

Comment: Sry i forgot to mention that we cant use any service at all.  Its complicated but i need a free service or if we can use g suite. Thats all

Comment: JumpCloud doesn't seem to be an appropriate solution for your use case anyway.